# If $A^X$ is equipotent to $B^X$ does it imply that A is equipotent to B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I was able to prove the converse of this statement to be true.However, I have some doubt whether the statement above is true. If true please provide a rigorous proof and if false please provide a counter-example or atleast a reason for the falsity of the statement.

Comment: If $X$ is a nonempty finite set, then this is true.  If $X$ is empty or infinite, then $\{0,1\}^X$ and $\mathbb{N}^X$ are equipotent.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a proof for finite X?

Comment: Does X have to be countably infinite or would it work for uncountable infinite X as well?

Comment: Can you suggest a textbook where I can find the topics related to these problems?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I do not study set theory, but topics like cardinal and ordinal numbers are important in my field of research, so I know about these topics.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $X$ is a nonempty finite set.  Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $\left|A^X\right|=\left|B^X\right|$.  We consider two cases.  First, suppose that $A$ is finite.  Then,
$$|B|\leq |B|^{|X|}=\left|B^X\right|=\left|A^X\right|=|A|^{|X|}<\infty\,,$$
whence $B$ is also finite.  Thus,
$$|B|^{|X|}=|A|^{|X|}\text{ implies }|B|=|A|\,.$$
Now, we assume that $A$ is infinite.  Then, it is well known (easy to prove) that $\alpha^n=\alpha$ for all infinite cardinal numbers $\alpha$ and for any positive integer $n$.  Thus, 
$$|A|=|A|^{|X|}=\left|A^X\right|=\left|B^X\right|=|B|^{|X|}=|B|\,.$$

Finally, we drop the condition that $X$ is a nonempty finite set. If $X=\emptyset$, then $$A^X=\{\emptyset\}=B^X$$ for any sets $A$ and $B$.  If $X$ is an infinite set, then
$$\left|A^X\right|=2^{|X|}=\left|B^X\right|$$
for all countable sets $A$ and $B$ with at least two elements.

Answer (score 0):

No, $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ has the same number of points as $\{0,1,2\}^\mathbb{N}$ but $\{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1,2\}$ do not.